# Swift Getting Character from Keycode Using CGEvent

Tags: swift3, cgeventtap

I have a key code from:

```
let keycode = event.GetIntegerValueField(.keyboardEventKeycode)
```

Is there way to translate it into a character?

```
func keyboardGetUnicodeString(maxStringLength: Int, actualStringLength: UnsafeMutablePointer <Int>?, unicodeString: UnsafeMutablePointer <UniChar>?)
```

It seems this is what I need, but it looks scary! Could someone explain how to call that function from swift? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var char = UniChar()
var length = 0
event.keyboardGetUnicodeString(maxStringLength: 1, actualStringLength: &length, unicodeString: &char)
```